# Change output of a SwiftUI Toggle

Tags: swift, swiftui, toggle, swift-playground

Is there a way to change the output of a SwiftUI Toggle. The default values are True and False but can I change to a pair of numbers e.g. 2 and 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just replace your code wherever you use the bool to

```
 yourBoolValue ? 2 : 0
```

Comment: How would I store this value because when I try and assign the output of the Toggle to an old variable it says: Binding<Bool> is not convertible to <Bool>

Comment: please show me your code than i can help you....best would be if it is runnable and compilable. normally     _yourvariable = true should work

Comment: Thank you so much, I opened another question with my code at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61714040/when-i-try-and-assign-the-output-of-the-toggle-to-an-old-variable-it-says-bindi